# Drombler FX Sample Application fails to run

Tags: drombler-fx

I followed the [getting startet instructions](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.8-SNAPSHOT/docs/tutorial/getting-started.html#gettingStarted) but cannot run it.

```
java -Djavafx.verbose=true -Dbinary.css=false -Djava.util.logging.config.file=target/deployment/standalone/conf/logging.properties -jar target/deployment/standalone/bin/foo.jar --userdir target/userdir
```

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.drombler.fx.startup.main.DromblerFXApplication**

Using the mvn exec:exec command yields the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar error when I used an OpenJDK runtime which was the default on my path. Make sure to meet the requirements:

> Java SE 8 with bundled JavaFX 8

Comment: Argh, misunderstanding error message. The class is found but not loaded. I checked the paths and fixed it. Thanks!